# issues in extracting text from PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to read a pdf using pypdf2 in python.
I have been using below code to read pdf.

```
import PyPDF2

filename = r'./abc.pdf'
pdf      = open(filename,'rb')
pdfReader= PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf)
page     = pdfReader.getPage(0)
text     = page.extractText()
print(text)
```

It displays text if I execute it on python command line.
It does not display text if I save it as script (with .py file extension) and run script.